# bootable USB drive and ISO images

Tags: installation, boot, live-usb, usb-drive, live-cd

I've some question regarding bootable pendrive and ISO.

- How to make a normal ISOimage(just containing folders) or USB  boot-able ,if one wants to do it manually, how to do it ?
- what is difference in BOOTSECTOR of normal pendrive and a bootable pendrive ?
- What if I have UBUNTU ISO(not a LIVE-CD) with all it's content, how to  make it bootable?

Answer (score 1):

An iso is like a program that only works when you BURN it to a disk or usb drive.

They have all the information you'll need to make a bootable usb drive at this link.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows